# when to assign a variable to itself when performing some method on any data structure?

Tags: python

I have a question about when to assign a variable when performing a method on a data type.

e.g. `nums = [1,2,3,4]`

Here we would not need to do `nums = nums.reverse()` but instead simply `nums.reverse()`

But in other cases like `nums = ["g","a","b"]`, we would need to do `nums = "".join(nums)`    then we can do something with nums. Otherwise `nums` still holds `["g","a","b"]`

How do we know when we need to assign it?

Comment: Because ```reverse``` is an in place function. It will return ```None```

Comment: Methods/functions that work in-place do not require re-assignment, indeed, since most of those methods/functions return `None`, re-assignment is probably *wrong*. For methods/functions that return a *new object*, then you usually need to assign it.

Comment: "How do we know when we need to assign it?" As with everything else: read the documentation to be aware what the function/method does.

Comment: Also, `nums` is a list, how would you convert it to a string in-place?

Comment: To know if it is an _in-place_ or _return-somthing_ kind-of-function you need to: **Read the documentation** of the function you are using.  Start here:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

The doc string is sometimes handy:

```
nums = [1,2,3]
print(nums.reverse.__doc__)
```

output:

```
Reverse *IN PLACE*.
```